# Network adapter not found when USB hub connected

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I am running Ubuntu 20.10 in an HP Spectre x360 15" from 2020. Yesterday I started to connect a USB hub during the login screen but I have realized that when I do that, network adapters are not found and therefore I cannot connect through WIFI.

I have the feeling that the kernel might get confused with some of the devices in the USB hub or something like that.

Is there a way to trigger the search/initialization of network adapters?

Does anybody understand why this is happening?

In case it can help; the devices connected to the USB hub are a cooling base for the laptop, a keyboard, a USB Bluetooth device for a wireless mouse and screen light (a light that sits on top of the screen).

Thank you in advance.

p.s. I have found that if I do "sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager" it works again. No clue why this is happening. A bit annoying if I have to do this every time I boot.

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the output of journalctl -u NetworkManager -b after plugging in the usb hub? Is anything plugged into the hub when you plug the hub into the computer

Comment: @PonJar I only see "info" or "warn" messages when I type the journalctl command. However, I was wrong, I think it worse than I thought. Besides of the network being down I cannot even shutdown the laptop. However I have discovered something; During the login screen, before typing my user password, I connect the USB hub, then I used to close the laptop lid and use my external screen and then Linux becomes crazy. However, if I keep the laptop lid open, login within Linux and after that I close the lid, everything is ok. So I think the lid is creating some unexpected behaviour.